# Remove space between chinese word and english word

Tags: fonts, spacing, languages, chinese

I'm writing a paragraph mix with Chinese characters and English characters, I found space between them. The space is especially huge when use `\ttfamily`. How can I remove those space?

```
Chinese中文english

Chinese中文{\ttfamily english}中文

\ \ \ remove this ↑
```

The pdf file looks like this:

[image: a little demo of my problem]

Comment: I think this has come up recently but please provide an example that we can run to see the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need `CJKecglue = {⟨glue⟩}`

设置 CJK 文字与西文、CJK 文字与行内数学公式之间的间距，默认值是一个空格。使用这个选项设置的 ⟨glue⟩ 最好也要用一定的弹性。请注意，这里设置的 ⟨glue⟩ 只影响 xeCJK 根据需要自动添加的空白，源文件中直接输入的 CJK 文字与西文之间的空格不受影响（直接输出）。有时候 xeCJK 可能不能正确地调整间距，需要手动加空格。

Set the distance between CJK characters and Western characters, CJK characters and in-line math formulas. The default value is a space. The ⟨glue⟩ set with this option should preferably use a certain amount of flexibility. Please note that the ⟨glue⟩ set here only affects the blanks automatically added by xeCJK as needed, and the spaces between the CJK text directly entered in the source file and Western languages are not affected (direct output). Sometimes xeCJK may not adjust the spacing correctly, and you need to add spaces manually.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\xeCJKsetup{CJKecglue={}}
\begin{document}
Chinese中文english

Chinese中文{\ttfamily english}中文
\end{document}
```